# sorting huge CSV file in pure Ruby and struggling with SQLesque type goal

Tags: ruby, sorting, csv

I am practically done with this csv manipulation, and ive learned a lot in the process having not used ruby in awhile, but I still am not quite sure how to

1. sort the unix timestamps in ascending order, lowest to highest
2. THEN and only then do the #each block where I limit the search_range and then figure out the key associated with the unix time stamp.

Example, I know by now that there are 12 rows that from a csv of 5000+ rows that are in between the start_date and end_date. Each timestamp has a unique key associated with it, but it's essential I have them in order going by start date or time stamp.

CSV files looks like this:

```
ID created_at  Key
1  1309380645  rubbish
2  1237178109  placeholder
3  1303585711  examples
4  1231175716  for learning
```

Here is my code that I've gotten thanks to some help earlier from people:

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'

start_date = DateTime.rfc3339('2014-06-22T00:00:00Z').to_time.to_i
end_date = DateTime.rfc3339('2014-07-22T00:00:00Z').to_time.to_i

keywords = []

search_range = (start_date..end_date)

my_csv = CSV.read('sample_data.csv', headers: true)

sorted_csv = my_csv.sort {|a, b| a[1].to_i <=> b[1].to_i}

sorted_csv.each do |row|
    next unless search_range.cover?(row['created_at'].to_i) 
    keywords << row['key']
end

puts keywords
```

I can confirm that the keys are not in order currently despite my best effort. Any help appreciated as always

Comment: ever thought of manipulating the csv with awk? - it can be much faster

Comment: i am aware there are other means, but I have already slaved away at this problem and specifically want a ruby answer

Comment: If it's a huge CSV file and you want to do DBM-like things, then use a database. SQLite can probably do what you want and it's easy to import and export the data. An ORM like Sequel or Active Record will help you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine, even though it might be slow for huge CSV file, and consume a decent amount of memory. Note that this code first selects the good rows and only then sorts them, to avoid sorting the whole CSV file :

```
require 'csv'

amounts = []

start_date = Time.new(2012, 1, 22)
end_date   = Time.new(2014, 7, 22)

search_range = (start_date.to_i..end_date.to_i)

all_rows = CSV.read('data.csv', headers: true, skip_blanks: true)

good_rows = all_rows.select do |row|
  search_range.cover?(row['created_at'].to_i)
end

good_rows.sort_by! { |row| row['created_at'].to_i }

amounts = good_rows.map { |row| row['purchase_amt'] }
```

UPDATE: 'created_at' column is used now, it was 'Unix_time' in your previous question.

Comment: this gives all the amts :(

Comment: btw the col_sep: \s always give me an illegal quoting in ln 2 error :/

Comment: something must be wrong with the good_rows output cause currently it isnt listing 12 rows which I know is the correct amount based off previous coding epiphanies tonight

Comment: I think its because #cover? returns true or false, whereas in the other instance we were using it to skip over lines UNLESS it were true...

Comment: I updated the answer. Column name was different. Is it any better now?

Comment: `next unless x` and `select x` should be equivalent.

Comment: yes thank you for sticking with me. I appreciate your help and sorry I lost focus as the night wore me out.

Comment: Don't worry. Not so long ago, all those Enumerable methods looked like voodoo to me. I wouldn't have spotted any difference either.

Comment: ive been in js land for too long and doing react stuff. Ruins your problem solving skills 0_0